# 64-bit inline assembly Microsoft Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, 64-bit, inline-assembly

Is there some kind of plugin, extension or something that would enable 64-bit inline assembly in Microsoft Visual Studio 2010?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/4ks26t93%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

> Programs with inline assembler code are not fully portable to other
>   hardware platforms. If you are designing for portability, avoid using
>   inline assembler.
>
> Inline assembly is not supported on the ARM and x64 processors.

Answer (score 2):

Not that I know of, but you don't really need it - you can simply assemble the assembly code separately and link it in. You don't even need a plugin for that, just right click the project, go to build customizations, and enable masm. Then you just add some assembly files.

If you don't really like masm with its "dword ptr" and strange semantics for variables and so on, you can use [yasm plugin](http://yasm.tortall.net/Download.html) (which is enabled in the same way, except you enable yasm in the build customizations instead of masm).